# Count the number of words in a lines in a file but ignoring Enter Key

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I am using the below command to count the number of words in the line but it gives the number of words plus one as the output.

```
awk '{ print length($0); }' abc.txt
```

How can I ignore the last character or enter key while counting the number of words in a line?

Answer (score 2):

gives no of chars

```
awk '{ print length($0); }' abc.txt
```

gives no of words, where field separator being single space

```
awk '{ print NF; }' abc.txt
```

Comment: The first command still counts the plus one than the number of the characters in the line

Comment: @RahulkumarBudhwani use second one which gives you no of fields/words in a line, it thinks that space is separator between words

Comment: the second one gives a number of words in the line. What I need is how to count a number of character in a line excluding the last character which is enter key.

Comment: @RahulkumarBudhwani why not just `awk '{ print length($0); }' abc.txt` it prints what you need

Comment: It counts one extra index which you can see if you have multiple lines in your text file and for the last line it doesn't count that extra index because there is no new line character in the last line.

Comment: @RahulkumarBudhwani will you please post your sample input and desired output

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the `NF` variable in `awk` like so?

```
  echo "this is a test" | awk '{print NF}'
```

Prints `4`.

I'm not sure what you expect to get out of printing the length of the whole like. That will give you the number of characters. Not the number of words.

Answer (score 0):

This awk script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { num=0 }
{
    num=num + NF
}
END {print num}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. This should print the number of fields in all of the *file*, the question asks `number of words in the line`.